# Checking if a condition is valid after saving to database, then executing an action -Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback

I've been trying to figure out how to update a field in a table when a condition becomes true.

My site checks if a workout has been completed by comparing two arrays. When the completedExercises array has the same workout_id's as the totalExercisesInWorkout array, it comes back as true. When I get true, I want to assign the user a new `workout_id`.

I think the best way to do this is with an `after_save` callback in the model, something like this:

```
after_save :is_workout_complete?

  protected
  def is_workout_complete?
    if @totalExercisesInWorkout.included_in?(@completedExercises) == true 
      current_user.workout_id = @workout.next_workout_id 
    end
  end
```

The problem is, The instance variables I'm calling are defined in the `application_controller` in an `initialize_vars` method, which isn't accessible here.

Should I define these instance variables somewhere else? I need them is several places

Is this the best way to check that the last exercise has been completed, then take an action on the user?

Comment: Seems that the whole block belongs to controller. There's no `current_user` in a model.

Comment: I don't think after_save works in the controller. I get this error when I try to move it: 'undefined method `after_save' for ApplicationController:Class'

Comment: yeah, I meant body of the method. How you will call it - that's the real question.

Comment: Ohh. I see what You're saying. Well hopefully someone will be able to help out with how to call it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem here was that I was defining things in the controller that really belonged in the model. If you want to access the current user, you need to write your method in the `User` model. An example is:

```
def add_initial_program
  prog_id = Program.for_user(self).first.id
  self.user_programs.build( :cycle_order => 1, :group_order => 1, :workout_order => 1, :program_id => prog_id)
end
```

In the above example I simply use self to refer to the User class, which is the current signed in user.